# Manually adding more records to a database table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help here, I need to add records to a database table and this table only has 1 column which is an int called numbers and this table already has 300 records and I need to add 2300 more rows while executing the query.

I put together a query here but I am not sure it will work so I need someone to look at it and make sure my query looks good or if I am missing something here.

query to add 2300 rows

```
DECLARE             @Numbers AS INT
SET                 @Numbers = 301
WHILE  @Numbers <= 2300
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers VALUES(@Numbers)
    SET @Numbers=@Numbers+1
END
```

Comment: This is only going to insert one row. `SET @Numbers = 2300  ... WHILE @Numbers <= 2300`

Comment: And after your update: `@Numbers >= 301` is false if you start at `300`, so the loop never executes. You should pay better attention.

Comment: my bad, I made the change now please look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `recursive` way ??

```
with t as (
     select 301 as Numbers 
     union all
     select Numbers+1
     from t
     where Numbers < 2300
)

insert into dbo.Numbers (Numbers)
select Numbers
from t
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

For your current `WHILE` loop, it should be start from `301` not `2300`

So, it should be

```
SET @Numbers = 301
WHILE @Numbers <= 2300
. . .
```

Comment: yes not sure why I didn't notice that, but I modified my first post, can you take a look if that would fix the issue please look above.

Comment: @AndresBryan29. . . Now you don't need to check first condition.

Comment: I removed the first condition please take a look.

Comment: thanks guys all your suggestions worked I was able to add the new 2300 rows to my table

Comment: why my questions is being mark as duplicate, even though my question description might look same as other questions but what I needed here is different results I could not find what I need it in other solutions.